# Calculate the average of the lowest n percentile

Tags: pandas, average, percentile

I have the following dataset. I want to find the average run of the lower 20 percentile. For example:
If I divide the ***runs*** column into 5 batches then the first two rows will be in the 20 percentile. So the average run of these two rows will be **(1+2)/2 = 1.5**
How do I divide the data frame into 5 batches (with sorting) and then find the average of that specific group?

I have tried using the following but the output shows 2.8 instead of 3

```
d.runs.quantile(0.2)
```

Input:

```
ODI_runs = {'name': ['Tendulkar', 'Sangakkara', 'Ponting', 
                      'Jayasurya', 'Jayawardene', 'Kohli', 
                      'Haq', 'Kallis', 'Ganguly', 'Dravid'], 
            'runs': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]} 
d = pd.DataFrame(ODI_runs)  

name            runs
Tendulkar       1
Sangakkara      2
Ponting         3
Jayasurya       4
Jayawardene     5
Kohli           6
Haq             7
Kallis          8
Ganguly         9
Dravid          10
```

Output:

```
1.5
```

Comment: This is a "write my code for me" type question. It does not mention what has been tried, and what exactly the issue is/where the asker is getting stuck. Add this info.

Comment: @Blend3rman, I have added the code that I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`pandas.DataFrame.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html#pandas-dataframe-quantile) method: to retrieve the value that separates the first 20% of the data we use `df["runs"].quantile(0.2)`. Then, is all pandas: use loc to target the correct rows and columns, and calculate the `.mean()` of thos values:

```
>> df.loc[df["runs"] <= df["runs"].quantile(0.2), "runs"].mean()
1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>>> df['runs'].sort_values().head(round(0.2*len(df))).mean()
1.5
```

If you want to get all results, use `pd.cut`:

```
labels = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th']
out = df['runs'].groupby(pd.cut(df['runs'], bins=5, labels=labels)).mean()
print(out)

# Output
runs
1st    1.5
2nd    3.5
3rd    5.5
4th    7.5
5th    9.5
Name: runs, dtype: float64
```